# Incompatibility between savetrees and amsart?

Tags: incompatibility, amsart, savetrees

I wish to print some notes that use the documentclass `amsart` in a more compact form.  I was hoping to simply use the `savetrees` package (maybe there is a more recent replacement?) but that seems to choke on equations:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{savetrees}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
...
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

gives `Extra \fi.` on the line containing `\end{equation}`, seemingly triggered by `\MT@tr@outer@r@`'s expansion containing `\fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \fi` etc.

What should I do to obtain a more compact version of `amsart`-typeset notes?

Comment: This is 'works for me' with the example you give and if I add something into the equation (`y = mx + c` is my usual). I have `amsart` v2.20.2 and `savetrees` v2.3.

Comment: I was going to suggest that we forward this to the latex team's expert on tex expansion issues, but....

Comment: I can't reproduce the error on an updated TeX Live; I also added `\lipsum[1-40]` to trigger the output routine.

Comment: have reproduced problem with tex live 2012 (`LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>`, `amsart  2009/07/02 v2.20.1` and `savetrees 2011/05/14 v2.0`),  since the other commenters are likely to be using more recent versions, my guess is that a later version of `savetrees` may be a solution.  the problem doesn't occur with `align` or `gather`, so (although it's not recommended) maybe that would be an alternative.  it also doesn't hang up on `\[ ... \]`, which is equivalent to `equation*`, so it seems the conflict may be related to label processing.

Comment: Ah, I seem to have an installation from around July 2011 on my Windows work machine.  It was installed a couple weeks ago.  Go figure.  I guess I'll have to bug the IT people for an update.  EDIT: how do I close this question as "too localized"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is an out-of-date system, and the op has requested closure.