# Undefined control sequence when using amsart and savetrees

Tags: amsart, savetrees

Are amsart and savetrees incompatible ([again](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283507/incompatibility-between-savetrees-and-amsart))? I am using texlive 2023, and `tlmgr` gives the following package versions:

```
savetrees 2.4
amscls 2.20.6
geometry 5.9
```

This test latex file

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{savetrees}

\begin{document}
\section{foo}
\end{document}
```

generates an `Undefined control sequence` error at the `\section` command:

```
$ latex test
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-01-04>
(/.../texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsart.cls
Document Class: amsart 2020/05/29 v2.20.6
(/.../texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/.../texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/.../texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/.../texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/.../texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/.../texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/.../texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/.../texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/savetrees/savetrees.sty
(/.../texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/.../texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/.../texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/.../texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
(/.../texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifpdf.sty
(/.../texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(/.../texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty))
(/.../texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty)
(/.../texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/.../texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty))
(/.../texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/.../texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def
) (./test.aux)
(/.../texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/.../texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: dvips
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...on\endcsname \protect \@secnumpunct 
                                                  
l.5 \section{foo}
                 
? 
[1] (./test.aux) )
Output written on test.dvi (1 page, 376 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Comment: `savetrees` makes assumptions about how the `\section` command runs and those assumptions are not correct for `amsart`. It is possible to patch away the error, but the heading will then also not be centered anymore (presumably because of savetrees).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `savetrees` loads `titlesec` which is not compatible with `amsart`.

Load it with the `sections=normal` option, so `titlesec` isn't loaded.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[sections=normal]{savetrees}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}

\kant[1-3]

\section{baz}

\kant[4-6]

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, you get essentially the same layout without `savetrees`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\addtolength{\textwidth}{170pt}
\addtolength{\textheight}{140pt}
\calclayout

\begin{document}

\section{foo}

\kant[1-3]

\section{baz}

\kant[4-6]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! (I needed ```bibliography=normal``` as well to make my actual document compile.)

Comment: @user108903 I added an alternative solution without `savetrees`. With `amsart` spacings are already tighter than with `article`.

Comment: I don't believe that there should be no space between the section number and the title.  I will check, but I think there's something wrong here.

Comment: I've checked.  There is definitely a space between the section number and the title.  Go to CTAN, look for `amsart`, open the "Instructions to authors" and go to page 6.  This documentation was prepared with `amsbook`, but the headings are uniformly defined for all AMS document classes.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I noticed it. But since `savetrees` can only be useful for rough drafts, I didn't investigate further.